# How to rotate a table with caption in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

For the following table, the caption does not rotate with the table. Can anyone help me in this regard?

```
\usepackage{array, booktabs, tabularx} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \label{table:NSFAccuDivBG}
  \caption{Comparative Performance of Subforests from Bagging}
  \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright \arraybackslash} X}
  \newcolumntype{S}{>{\centering \arraybackslash} X}
  \newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash} X}
  \begin{sideways}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} {>{\setlength\hsize{.12\hsize}}R >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T}  % centered columns (4 columns)
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{4}{r}{EA} & \multicolumn{4}{r}{ES} \\
  \cmidrule(l){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
  DS & $ Sub_{A} $ & $ Sub_{D} $ & $ Sub_{A \cap D} $ & $ Sub_{All} $ & $ Sub_{A} $ & $ Sub_{D} $ & $ Sub_{A \cap D} $ & $ Sub_{All} $ \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  BS & 79.24 & 84.33 & 77.75 & 80.50 & 51.90 & 49.20 & 9.10 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  BC & 77.83 & 77.30 & 75.81 & 77.92 & 55.80 & 46.30 & 12.30 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  CE & 90.96 & 83.29 & 87.44 & 91.19 & 84.90 & 29.70 & 14.70 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  CHES & 94.84 & 83.97 & 82.16 & 95.22 & 72.40 & 42.90 & 15.30 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  CA & 86.68 & 81.16 & 83.76 & 86.07 & 76.80 & 40.90 & 18.50 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  DER & 87.82 & 62.03 & 73.37 & 86.96 & 64.40 & 37.20 & 4.50 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  EC & 84.62 & 85.43 & 85.43 & 84.97 & 60.00 & 38.20 & 13.60 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  GI & 74.12 & 69.83 & 68.95 & 74.12 & 59.90 & 40.80 & 15.10 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  HR & 72.62 & 73.39 & 63.39 & 69.54 & 49.30 & 49.30 & 13.10 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  HEP & 86.25 & 85.00 & 81.25 & 86.25 & 71.70 & 43.40 & 17.80 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  IS & 97.19 & 97.23 & 95.80 & 97.14 & 70.60 & 27.60 & 15.90 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  ION & 94.02 & 93.45 & 93.17 & 93.73 & 52.50 & 47.50 & 12.90 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  IRS & 95.33 & 93.33 & 84.00 & 96.00 & 54.20 & 26.90 & 9.50 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  LM & 74.72 & 75.00 & 51.11 & 76.11 & 50.20 & 49.50 & 2.40 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  LD & 68.40 & 68.36 & 66.63 & 71.48 & 62.30 & 42.70 & 20.20 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  PID & 76.22 & 75.83 & 75.38 & 75.95 & 60.20 & 41.90 & 22.50 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  SON & 80.86 & 81.07 & 27.00 & 83.07 & 52.10 & 48.20 & 1.30 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  SH & 82.96 & 82.97 & 80.37 & 82.96 & 51.40 & 47.00 & 10.70 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  SV & 74.27 & 74.02 & 73.05 & 74.14 & 59.70 & 42.90 & 13.30 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  TN & 95.04 & 95.99 & 93.90 & 94.56 & 60.50 & 38.70 & 8.30 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  \textbf{Avg} & 83.70 & 81.15 & 75.99 & \textbf{83.89} \cellcolor[gray] {.8} & 61.04 & 41.54 & 12.55 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{sideways}
 \end{table}
```

Comment: I am using the following packages: \usepackage{array, booktabs, tabularx}, \usepackage{setspace}, \usepackage{multirow} and \usepackage{rotating} related to Table.

Answer (score 17):

Well, there are several errors in your code.  You need not `table`, you should use `sidewaystable`instead.  `\label` has to follow `\caption` or your reference to the table will **not** work!

Please check the following MWE (main changes marked with `% <=========`):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx}

\begin{document}

%\begin{table}

  \begin{sidewaystable}% <===============================================
  \caption{Comparative Performance of Subforests from Bagging}\label{table:NSFAccuDivBG}% <===============================================
  \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright \arraybackslash} X}
  \newcolumntype{S}{>{\centering \arraybackslash} X}
  \newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash} X}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} {>{\setlength\hsize{.12\hsize}}R >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T}  % centered columns (4 columns)
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{4}{r}{EA} & \multicolumn{4}{r}{ES} \\
  \cmidrule(l){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
  DS & $ Sub_{A} $ & $ Sub_{D} $ & $ Sub_{A \cap D} $ & $ Sub_{All} $ & $ Sub_{A} $ & $ Sub_{D} $ & $ Sub_{A \cap D} $ & $ Sub_{All} $ \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  BS & 79.24 & 84.33 & 77.75 & 80.50 & 51.90 & 49.20 & 9.10 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  BC & 77.83 & 77.30 & 75.81 & 77.92 & 55.80 & 46.30 & 12.30 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  CE & 90.96 & 83.29 & 87.44 & 91.19 & 84.90 & 29.70 & 14.70 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  CHES & 94.84 & 83.97 & 82.16 & 95.22 & 72.40 & 42.90 & 15.30 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  CA & 86.68 & 81.16 & 83.76 & 86.07 & 76.80 & 40.90 & 18.50 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  DER & 87.82 & 62.03 & 73.37 & 86.96 & 64.40 & 37.20 & 4.50 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  EC & 84.62 & 85.43 & 85.43 & 84.97 & 60.00 & 38.20 & 13.60 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  GI & 74.12 & 69.83 & 68.95 & 74.12 & 59.90 & 40.80 & 15.10 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  HR & 72.62 & 73.39 & 63.39 & 69.54 & 49.30 & 49.30 & 13.10 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  HEP & 86.25 & 85.00 & 81.25 & 86.25 & 71.70 & 43.40 & 17.80 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  IS & 97.19 & 97.23 & 95.80 & 97.14 & 70.60 & 27.60 & 15.90 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  ION & 94.02 & 93.45 & 93.17 & 93.73 & 52.50 & 47.50 & 12.90 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  IRS & 95.33 & 93.33 & 84.00 & 96.00 & 54.20 & 26.90 & 9.50 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  LM & 74.72 & 75.00 & 51.11 & 76.11 & 50.20 & 49.50 & 2.40 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  LD & 68.40 & 68.36 & 66.63 & 71.48 & 62.30 & 42.70 & 20.20 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  PID & 76.22 & 75.83 & 75.38 & 75.95 & 60.20 & 41.90 & 22.50 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  SON & 80.86 & 81.07 & 27.00 & 83.07 & 52.10 & 48.20 & 1.30 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  SH & 82.96 & 82.97 & 80.37 & 82.96 & 51.40 & 47.00 & 10.70 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  SV & 74.27 & 74.02 & 73.05 & 74.14 & 59.70 & 42.90 & 13.30 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  TN & 95.04 & 95.99 & 93.90 & 94.56 & 60.50 & 38.70 & 8.30 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  \textbf{Avg} & 83.70 & 81.15 & 75.99 & \textbf{83.89} \cellcolor[gray] {.8} & 61.04 & 41.54 & 12.55 & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: The "EA" and "ES" headers aren't centered over their respective column groups.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using a dedicated environment such as `sidewaystable` (provided by the `rotating` package), you should consider  (a) correcting the position of the headers "EA" and "ES" and (b)simplifying your table structure drastically. AFAICT, it suffices to use the `T` column type, without width adjustments, for all eight data columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash} X}
\newcommand\Sub{{\textit{Sub}}}
\begin{document}

  \begin{sidewaystable}
  \caption{Comparative Performance of Subforests from Bagging}
  \label{table:NSFAccuDivBG} 
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} { l *{8}{T} }  
  \toprule
  DS & \multicolumn{4}{c}{EA} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{ES} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
     & $\Sub_{A}$ & $\Sub_{D}$ & $\Sub_{A \cap D}$ & $\Sub_{\textit{All}}$ 
     & $\Sub_{A}$ & $\Sub_{D}$ & $\Sub_{A \cap D}$ & $\Sub_{\textit{All}}$ \\
  \midrule
  BS & 79.24 & 84.33 & 77.75 & 80.50 & 51.90 & 49.20 & 9.10 & 100.00 \\
  BC & 77.83 & 77.30 & 75.81 & 77.92 & 55.80 & 46.30 & 12.30 & 100.00 \\
  CE & 90.96 & 83.29 & 87.44 & 91.19 & 84.90 & 29.70 & 14.70 & 100.00 \\
  CHES & 94.84 & 83.97 & 82.16 & 95.22 & 72.40 & 42.90 & 15.30 & 100.00 \\
  CA & 86.68 & 81.16 & 83.76 & 86.07 & 76.80 & 40.90 & 18.50 & 100.00 \\
  DER & 87.82 & 62.03 & 73.37 & 86.96 & 64.40 & 37.20 & 4.50 & 100.00 \\
  EC & 84.62 & 85.43 & 85.43 & 84.97 & 60.00 & 38.20 & 13.60 & 100.00 \\
  GI & 74.12 & 69.83 & 68.95 & 74.12 & 59.90 & 40.80 & 15.10 & 100.00 \\
  HR & 72.62 & 73.39 & 63.39 & 69.54 & 49.30 & 49.30 & 13.10 & 100.00 \\
  HEP & 86.25 & 85.00 & 81.25 & 86.25 & 71.70 & 43.40 & 17.80 & 100.00 \\
  IS & 97.19 & 97.23 & 95.80 & 97.14 & 70.60 & 27.60 & 15.90 & 100.00 \\
  ION & 94.02 & 93.45 & 93.17 & 93.73 & 52.50 & 47.50 & 12.90 & 100.00 \\
  IRS & 95.33 & 93.33 & 84.00 & 96.00 & 54.20 & 26.90 & 9.50 & 100.00 \\
  LM & 74.72 & 75.00 & 51.11 & 76.11 & 50.20 & 49.50 & 2.40 & 100.00 \\
  LD & 68.40 & 68.36 & 66.63 & 71.48 & 62.30 & 42.70 & 20.20 & 100.00 \\
  PID & 76.22 & 75.83 & 75.38 & 75.95 & 60.20 & 41.90 & 22.50 & 100.00 \\
  SON & 80.86 & 81.07 & 27.00 & 83.07 & 52.10 & 48.20 & 1.30 & 100.00 \\
  SH & 82.96 & 82.97 & 80.37 & 82.96 & 51.40 & 47.00 & 10.70 & 100.00 \\
  SV & 74.27 & 74.02 & 73.05 & 74.14 & 59.70 & 42.90 & 13.30 & 100.00 \\
  TN & 95.04 & 95.99 & 93.90 & 94.56 & 60.50 & 38.70 & 8.30 & 100.00 \\
  \midrule
  \textbf{Avg} & 83.70 & 81.15 & 75.99 & \cellcolor[gray]{.8} \textbf{83.89} 
               & 61.04 & 41.54 & 12.55 & 100.00 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to place the table and caption inside a `minipage`, as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright \arraybackslash} X}
  \newcolumntype{S}{>{\centering \arraybackslash} X}
  \newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash} X}
  \begin{sideways}
  \begin{minipage}{\textheight} % here
  \caption{Comparative Performance of Subforests from Bagging}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} {
    >{\setlength\hsize{.12\hsize}}R
    >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T
    % ... rest of column definitions ...
    >{\setlength\hsize{.11\hsize}}T
  }  % centered columns (4 columns)
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{4}{r}{EA} & \multicolumn{4}{r}{ES} \\
  \cmidrule(l){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
  DS & $ Sub_{A} $ & ... & $ Sub_{All} $ \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  BS & 79.24 & ... & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  BC & 77.83 & ... & 100.00 
  % ... rest of table ...
  SV & 74.27 & ... & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  TN & 95.04 & ... & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  \textbf{Avg} & 83.70 & ... & 100.00 \tabularnewline
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{minipage} % and here
  \end{sideways}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

See also: [Wikibooks LaTeX, Rotations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rotations).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to replace the nested `table`, `sideways`, and `minipage` environments with a single `sidewaystable` environment?

Comment: @Mico: sure, that's what [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277710/55879) did. I admit that I don't know a whole lot about rotating tables or what OP's constraints are, so I tried to make a solution as close to theirs as possible, but `sidewaystable` seems like a good solution.